# Created login form in Android using Laravel API, but I have some errors

Tags: javascript, android

```
private void usepost(String email, String password) {


            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(SERVER_URL)
                    .build();

            Interface service = retrofit.create(Interface.class);
```

In this line results in an error, how can we rectify the error?

```
Call<ServerResponse> call = service.POST("POST",email, password);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ServerResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        ResObj resObj = (ResObj) response.body();
                        assert resObj != null;
                        if (resObj.getMessage().equals("true")) {
                            //login start main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    //                            intent.putExtra("email", email);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The Email or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: `I have some errors` than share error with question

Comment: Whats the error ? Add it with question .

Comment: define your error and url when to post data and what response given after post data into server.

Comment: Post Data: @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("signup")
    Call Create(@Body Product product);
    }                                   Url:http://api.hallohours.in/                  Error:Call<ServerResponse> call = service.POST("POST",email, password);